# How to make a timestamp field on AWS Console for date on custom fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on creating a custom field on AWS Cognito but I only see string and number, while my use case if to store timestamp, can you please suggest how I could define this on Console if it's possible to make it a timestamp, or your suggestion on making it string or number?

Answer (score 1):

There are no other data types available. Just serialize it when you store it and de-serialize it when you retrieve it. Stick to a standard like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and you can take advantage of built-ins and standard libraries.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that been thinking there is other hack I can do around. Thanks  @Andrew